# fullcalendar with resourceDay, update list of resources

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar v1.5.4 with the resourceDay view (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9c9ce0d84a6a73080177). My problem is when I am trying to update the list of resources. I can just run `setCalendar()` but it's quite a big and resource expensive function:

```
setCalendar = function (defaultView, element, currentDate) {
  myCal = $(element);

  myCal.fullCalendar({
    minTime: '07:00:00',
    maxTime: '23:59:00',
    cache: true,
    editable: true,
    eventStartEditable: true,
    eventDurationEditable: true,
    ...
    resources: [ resourcesArray ],

    dayClick: function (date, event, t, r) {
      ...
    }

  ...
  });
}
```

Running all of this code every time I want to update the columns of the resourceDay view is too expensive so I am trying to update only the list of columns (resources) and rerender them. In the `function ResourceManager` of the gist that I linked above (row 1257) you can see that I have tried to lift the function that populates the list of resources. By adding `t._addResourceSources = _addResourceSources;` and then calling on it from this function:

```
updateCalendar = function () {
  myCal.fullCalendar('_addResourceSources', resourcesArray);
};
```

This is printing the new list to the console (row 1305) but I need assistance with rerendering it so the calendar actually uses the new list of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `myCal.fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );`

http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_rendering/rerenderEvents/

It may not work though, I don't know how resources work exactly and I'm more familiar with the v2 of fullCalendar.